# Can I re-use a spirits measure cup for different spirits?

Tags: spirits, serving

I have a stainless steel jigger measuring cup for UK spirits measures, like this image:

[image: Jig]

The alcohol does not seem to 'stick' to the jig cup, so is it okay to use the cup to, say, measure a gin drink then re-use it for, say, a vodka drink, without rinsing the cup?

Or should I always wash or rinse the jig before re-use for either a different spirit or a different brand of the same spirit?

Should I have separate measuring cups for different spirits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A purist would say always rinse.

A normal person would say don't worry about it.

A pragmatist would say measure the vodka before the gin and no one will be able to tell the difference.